# Extract numbers before any letter or special sign within cell content

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A                  B              C
1   125Product             125
2   58968Brand           58968
3   74Category              74
4   6325Product           6325
5   2:2                     2:
6   7489Category458    7489Bra
7   29:Brand                29
8
```

In **Column A** I have contents consisting of numbers, letters or special characters. 
In **Column B** I want to extract all numbers **before** any letter or special character; therefore, I use the following formula:

```
=LEFT(A2,SUM(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},""))))
```

This formula works for all values except for the values in Cell `A5` and `A6`.
I guess the issue is that in this cell - instead of all the other values - there is a another number after the letter/special character.

What do I need to change in my formula to only extract the numbers **before** any letter or special character?

Comment: This should help,
https://superuser.com/questions/874105/finding-the-first-non-numeric-character-in-a-string

Comment: Are commas and full stops/periods taken as part of the number or special characters?

Comment: As part of the special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Formula used in `B1`:

```
=LEFT(A1,MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)*1),0)-1)
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you don't want to enter as array, use:

```
=LEFT(A1,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)*1),0),0)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.